# Error while saving entities into the database using Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I created an entity class (`User.java`) and repository interface (`UserRepository.java`). If I run my application everything would be fine (item table would be created). Then I add `DBInit` class with `run()` method and `userRepository.saveAll(users);` produces an error. I just tried to create 3 users and add them to the database using Spring Data Jpa. So why I have an error and how to get rid of it?
`DBInit.run()` method produces an error
User.java

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int id;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String surname;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "telephone_number", nullable = false)
    private String telephoneNumber;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String country;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String address;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    // delimiter = ";"
    private String roleNames;
    
    public User(String name, String surname, String password, String telephoneNumber, String email, String country, String address, String roleNames)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.password = password;
        this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.country = country;
        this.address = address;
        this.roleNames = roleNames;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
import Onlinestore.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>
{
    User findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

DBInit.java

```
import Onlinestore.entity.User;
import Onlinestore.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DBInit implements CommandLineRunner
{
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    public DBInit(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String[] args)
    {
        User user1 = new User("name1", "surname1", passwordEncoder.encode("pass1"),
                "+111111111", "email1", "country1", "address1", "USER");

        User user2 = new User("name2", "surname2" + "", passwordEncoder.encode("pass2"),
                "+111111111", "email2", "country2", "address2", "USER");

        User user3 = new User("admin", "admin", passwordEncoder.encode("admin123"),
                "123", "123", "123", "132", "ADMIN");

        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(user1, user2, user3);

        userRepository.saveAll(users);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/online_store
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Console output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user
        (address, country, email, name, password, role_names, surname, telephone_number, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-12-27 22:59:29.145  WARN 7952 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2021-12-27 22:59:29.145 ERROR 7952 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error: syntax error (approximate position: "user")
  Position: 13
2021-12-27 22:59:29.145  INFO 7952 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-12-27 22:59:29.145  INFO 7952 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-27 22:59:29.161 ERROR 7952 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:751) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at Onlinestore.BootSecurityApplication.main(BootSecurityApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy94.saveAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at Onlinestore.service.DBInit.run(DBInit.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1402) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3285) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2420) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: syntax error (approximate position: "user")
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2674) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2364) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:484) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:404) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:162) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2021-12-27 22:59:29.192  INFO 7952 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-12-27 22:59:29.192  INFO 7952 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-12-27 22:59:29.192  INFO 7952 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Try to annotate your Entity with the different name so it doesn't user the default User, user is reversed keyword in Spring data jpa. eg @Entity
@Table(name="customer")

Comment: @joemokenela it works just fine. Maybe post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: thank you @Denis_newbie , I have added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the name of the table that gets created  from your `@Entity` becomes the name of your entity class in small caps, in this case "user" and this happens to be reserved and you won't be able to create a table with that name.

You can override the *(default)* name of the resulting table to be created by annotating your entity with `@Table(name = "otherName")` and giving it another name of your choice.